# how to add sms feature to an app to the selected phone number in a listview...... so far i can make a call to the selected number

Tags: android, listview, sms

so far i didn't got answer to my question.. i  will be thankful if anyone can just help me out. when we select a number from ListView , we must be able send a message to that number. i didn't understand where to start.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("sms:" +num));
            intent.putExtra("sms_body", "message");
            startActivity(intent);
```

but i want the message to be given after selecting the number.. the msg must be dynamic

Comment: you can put the above code inside listview.setOnItemClickListner() method.

Comment: are you using default contacts list?

Answer (score 0):

`onClick` event of your list , either invoke 
a custom `Dialog`/`Fragment`/`Activity` to enter message and mobile number.

Get the content of your message from `EditText` (messageContent)

Get the number to which you need to send message from `EditText` (mobNumber)

Now use the below code.

```
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
smsManager.sendTextMessage(mobNumber.getText().toString(), null, messageContent.getText().toString(), null, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this Code**

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                smsManager.sendTextMessage("selected phone number", null,
                        "your sms message", null, null);
            }
        });
```